# Retrieve data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a table like

`tbl_scripts`

```
script_unique_id | system_id | script_name
+-----------------------------------------+
12345            |  89784    |   Demo
```

And another table goes as

`tbl_allowed_group_ids`

```
system_id | script_unique_id |allowed_group_id
+---------------------------------------------+
89784       12345             56987
```

So now what I want is the row from `tbl_scripts` with `group_id` only if the unique id is in `allowed_group_id`

What I tried is this but is nowhere close to it....I know this is completely wrong

```
SELECT script_name FROM tbl_scripts WHERE script_unique_id = allowed_group_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables:

```
select *
from tbl_scripts s
left join tbl_allowed_group_ids g
  on s.system_id = g.system_id 
  and s.script_unique_id = g.script_unique_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c43/1)

If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows in the `tbl_scripts` table regardless of whether or not it has a matching row in the `tbl_allowed_group_ids` table. If you only want matching rows, then you can use an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.script_name
FROM tbl_scripts t1
INNER JOIN tbl_allowed_group_ids  t2 ON t1.script_unique_id = t2.allowed_group_id
```